# Can't Keep DataGridView Column from Resizing

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, resize

I have a class that inherits from a DataGridView with 9 columns. I have set these columns to be a fixed length, but one of them (index 5) automatically resizes the width when I manually resize the container.

All of the other columns are working as expected, and I have tried to lock this column as well, when creating it.

```
        Dim column5 As DGVTextBoxColumn = _
            .AddTextBoxColumn(5, "Contact", "Contact", _colNameWidth)
        '   HIGH: This cell keeps resizing no matter what I seem to do.
        column5.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        column5.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False
```

Setting Resizable to False and AutoSizeMode to None for the column did nothing. Since this is code that someone else wrote many years ago, I figured that perhaps it was being set to resize somewhere else in the code. I searched, but could not find it. Finally I added an event to Resize that would turn resizing off for the row.

```
Private Sub WorklistGrid_Resize(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    If (Not _columnsLocked AndAlso Me.Columns.Count > 6) Then
        Me.Columns(5).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None
        Me.Columns(5).Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False
    End If
End Sub
```

I have confirmed that this is being called when I try to resize the DataGridView, but the column in question still gets resized. Just to be on the safe side, I also created a For Next loop in this method, and set all columns to no avail.

I must be overlooking something obvious; probably playing with the wrong Property. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious "have you turned it off and on again" question, but just to make sure, we're certain that it's index 5 and not another index?

Comment: Also, if these columns are being dynamically added instead of permanently, there maybe something with the datagridview's settings that is overwriting it later.

Comment: @sparkysword: Thank you for the reply. I did consider that I might somehow be targeting the wrong column, so I modified it to use a for loop and set all columns, rather than just 5. Since this is happening in an event when the user tries to resize the control, I can't imagine that something would be changing it back. I'm locking the column when I first create it, and again right before I resize it.

Comment: Hrm, so it isn't setting it to a bad width before hand, but does after you resize it. Is there a way that you can print out the sender's information and properties? Possibly to see what exactly is telling it to resize to that "bad" value and get to that point in your code.

Comment: but then again if it is sending that in the first place, then it's probably your mouse. Maybe the best way to fix this is to cancel the resize if it's that column in this event call. I.e. if (column 5) e.cancel

Comment: @sparkysword: The column width is just absorbing the resize. All columns are staying the same except for this one, which gets larger as the control gets larger. Sorry if I didn't explain that well enough.

Comment: What is the value of the grids AutoSizeColumnsMode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well, if it keeps getting larger, a workaround might be to just set its with in the resize. If column(5) then column.width = 80 or whatever. If that doesn't work, then it's something outside that.

Comment: @sparkyword: Well, I don't like the brute force route, but it worked. At this point, working is better than elegant. Thank you for your suggestion. If you want to write it up, I will select it as an answer.